# parsing base64 to server returns null in Json when using JsonConvert.SerializeObject();

Tags: c#, php, .net, xamarin, base64

So there I was all happy parsing data to my server using FormUrlEncodedContent(); when I decided to add an image converted to string using Base64 and received an error saying that the URL was to long. On research I then changed this to JsonConvert.SerializeObject(); but in my code the Json now return null. Could some one look at my code please and suggest what i should do instead? I did try replacing IEnumerable with the object instead but got the same error
The process goes through but all data on the server is null.

the json error is as follows:
[0:] Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: M. Path '', line 0, position 0.
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue () [0x002b3] in :0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read () [0x0004c] in :0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAndMoveToContent () [0x00000] in :0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType (Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, System.Boolean hasConverter) [0x0004a] in :0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, System.Boolean checkAdditionalContent) [0x000db] in :0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00054] in :0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (System.String value, System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x0002d] in :0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value) [0x00000] in :0

```
 IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queries = new 
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
        {                   
                  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("widget1", Widget1),
                  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("widget2", Widget2),
                  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("widget3", 
Widget3),
                  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("widget4", Widget4),
                  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("widget5", Widget5),
                  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("encoding_string", 
encoding_string)                 
    };


        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queries);       
        //HttpContent q = new FormUrlEncodedContent(queries);
       HttpContent q = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, 
"application/json");

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, 
q))
            {
                using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                {

                    string mycontent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                   Console.WriteLine("mycontent1 " + mycontent);



            }

        }
    }
}
```

Json string as follows i have shortened the image as it was to long for the post

jsonString [{"Key":"widget1","Value":"54"},{"Key":"widget2","Value":"test"},{"Key":"widget3","Value":"test"},{"Key":"widget4","Value":"100"},{"Key":"widget5","Value":"3"},{"Key":"encoding_string","Value":"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"}]

Comment: Are you trying to pass a base_64 encoded string over HTTP, on the URI? Hung up on the "URL was too long" bit.

Comment: yes but another post said to use JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queries);    to resolve the issue but all my variables are null when i use this

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to transport base64 data with no URL encoding. Those `+` and `=`  in the base64 encoding will not survive transport on the URL. A string of JSON is not URL safe necessarily. Look at HttpUtility.UrlEncode? Can you POST this instead?

Comment: thanks for your input but i think i took care off the base64 to string using the following code or have i misunderstood?                                                                                            var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
            await stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
            base64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            file.Dispose();

Comment: Is the generated JSON something you can share? Could see if its what I'm thinking and probably provide a better example of fix.

Comment: Well because of the image its quite long but will give it a go

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176284/discussion-between-ficuscr-and-whitefinger).

Comment: That JSON is valid except for a missing quote on: `{"Key":"widget4,"Value":"100"}`... Should be: `{"Key":"widget4","Value":"100"}`. With that correction it passes linter. Assuming you are not manipulating the string... maybe a double encoding issue? Web helper? All that comes to mind but not sure it fits.

Comment: Ha yeah, I had manipulated the string before posting and missed my quote lol but thanks for checking, well thanks for confirming that it should work, perhaps i will look into doing it a different way :(

Comment: I suppose if the Json string is there but not when it gets to the server perhaps its timing out will look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turned out once it was confirmed that my  code was  correct I looked deeper at my PHP code and I was using POST instead of json_decode and once I implemented this it all started to work thanks all for your help inconfirming there was nothing wrong